# Como pasar datos de un .aspx.cs a un .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp, aspx

estoy empezando con .net, y tengo un botón en mi página pruebas.aspx que tiene este código:

```
<asp:Button type ="button" ID="prueba"  runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="prueba" OnClick="prueba_Click" />
```

En el archivo pruebas.aspx.cs tengo lo siguiente:

```
  protected static prueba_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            return 'todo Ok';
        }
```

Pero no logro hacer que salga en la web principal de pruebas.aspx, alguien sabe como puedo hacer que el .aspx.cs mande los datos al .aspx y pintarlos?? muchas gracias

Comment: Has probado a cambiar `protected` por `public`?

Comment: En que cambiaría eso??

Comment: A poder utilizar la función fuera de la clase, tal vez por eso te esté generando problemas, desconozco si eso puede solucionarlo, pero puedes probar a ver si así funciona

Comment: He cambiado la forma y he puesto en el aspx <%=prueba %> y si le doy un valor a prueba en el .cs me sale bién, pero si lo meto en una función me dice que public is not valid for this item

Comment: public void procedimientoDePrueba()
            {
                prueba= "hola";
            }

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un label en tu página:

```
<asp:Label ID="MiLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>

<asp:Button type ="button" ID="prueba"  runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="prueba" OnClick="prueba_Click" />
```

Luego del lado del servidor, en el método:

```
protected static prueba_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MiLabel.Text = "todo Ok";
}
```

Y listo.